# Testing TestNG listeners

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng

I have a test A that programmatically runs another test B and test A passes only if test B fails. I want the build to succeed only when test A passes.

Precisely, I implemented TestNG listener (`MyListener`). I need to verify whether it is handling results of failing tests properly. The only approach to test it seems to have test A (`testListener`) run another test B (`AlwaysFailingTest`) [programmatically](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically) and check the results.

```
@Test
public void testListener() {
    System.setProperty("knownBugs", "execute");
    tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
    TestNG testng = new TestNG();
    testng.setTestClasses(new Class[]{AlwaysFailingTest.class});
    testng.addListener(tla);
    testng.addListener(new MyListener());
    testng.run();
    assertThat(tla.getSkippedTests().size(), equalTo(0));
    assertThat(tla.getFailedTests().size(), equalTo(1));
    assertThat(tla.getPassedTests().size(), equalTo(0));
}
```

However, I don't want the test that is failing on purpose to impact test results of my library. Currently, for `mvn clean test` it is like that:

```
Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.407 sec <<< FAILURE!
shouldAlwaysFail(com.testing.listeners.MyListenerTest$AlwaysFailingTest)  Time elapsed: 0.01 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: Failing as always
        at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:94)
        at com.testing.listeners.MyListenerTest$AlwaysFailingTest.shouldAlwaysFail(MyListenerTest.java:99)
```

`testListener()` method is passing, that's great, but why results of the `AlwaysFailingTest` appear in the library test results, I don't understand. How can I avoid that?

I listed full code of `MyListener` and `MyListenerTest` [here](https://gist.github.com/dzieciou/1addcc19e0d465afa3e8).

Comment: Could you share a more complete example (via a gist?)? It is difficult to follow.

Comment: @juherr:Thanks. I listed full code of `MyListener` and `MyListenerTest` here: https://gist.github.com/dzieciou/1addcc19e0d465afa3e8

Comment: You should have a look at arquillian-governor http://arquillian.org/blog/2015/12/13/arquillian-governor-1-0-1-Final/

Comment: And in your case, prefer IMethodInterceptor or set the test result (to skip?) http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#methodinterceptors

Answer (score 1):

`shouldAlwaysFail` is being executed twice: once by the main test suite and once programatically by the `testListener` test. As it always fails the main test suite results will contain the failure. To fix this you can exclude the `shouldAlwaysFail` test from the main test suite so that it only gets run programmatically by the `testListener` test.

You can configure Maven Surefire to exclude your test:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/AlwaysFailingTest.java</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Or configure TestNG to exclude your test:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="SuiteName" verbose="1">
    <test name="TestName">
        <packages>
            <package name="com.testing.listeners"/>
        </packages>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.testing.listeners.AlwaysFailingTest">
                <methods>
                    <exclude name="shouldAlwaysFail"/>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

See [Maven Surefire Plugin – Inclusions and Exclusions of Tests](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html) and/or [TestNG Documentation - 3 - testng.xml](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml) for more details.

Comment: Excluding AlwaysFailingTest does not work because it is run programmatically by `testListener()` method, not by SureFire directly.

Comment: Let me clarify, I have a test A that runs another test B and test A will pass only if test B fails. I want the build to succeed only when test A passes.

Comment: @dzieciou I originally neglected to explain in my answer why you are getting the test failure in your test results. I've updated my answer with such. Excluding `AlwaysFailingTest` should work because it only excludes it from the main suite and not the "sub-suite" you create when you run it programmatically by `testListener`.

Comment: It worked only when I moved `AlwaysFailingTest` to a separate class. When I was trying to do the same for inner class (`MyListenerTest.AlwaysFailingTest`) it was running the test. Seems like a bug in TestNG or surefire plugin?

Comment: I had the same issue. What confused me more was that the documentation for [`excludes`](https://maven.apache.org/components/surefire-archives/surefire-2.17/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#excludes) states that the default value excludes inner classes but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use "expectedExceptions" attribute of the @Test annotation so that the test will expect it to always FAIL and will not stop your execution.

```
@Test(expectedExceptions=AssertionError.class)
    public void test(){
        Assert.fail();
    }
```

Comment: Because then the following assertion would fail: `assertThat(tla.getFailedTests().size(), equalTo(1));`.

Comment: you can take that assertion out from that place :)

Comment: That's nonsense. The goal of this assertion is to verify whether for this particular case Listener does not change number of failing tests.

Comment: also just a loud thought..did u consider using mockito for such kind of testing

Comment: What would you mock here?